# React Native Text Input closes on every keystroke

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Libraries used : React Native Paper, React Navigation.
React Native 0.70.4

using useState hook to store the input value, here is my code:

```
// necessary react imports
const [search, setSearch] = useState<string>('');
const theme = useAreteTheme(); // react-native-paper theme
const {consumers, setConsumers} = useConsumerStore(); // zustand store not related to input
        <TextInput
        value={search}
        onChangeText={text => setSearch(text)}
        placeholder="Search Patient"
        returnKeyType="search"
        onBlur={searchConsumerHandler}
        left={<TextInput.Icon icon="account-search" />}
        style={styles.input}
      />
```

Additionally i have this component in Flatlist component like this:

```
<FlatList
  data={[]}
  renderItem={null}
  ListHeaderComponent={() => <>{children}</>}
  style={styles.scrollMain}
  />
```

Comment: Is this happening on IOS simulator?

Comment: Share more code .

Comment: this is happening in android emulator and android physical device.

Answer (score 0):

do you happen to have this input component inside the header of a scroll or flat list?
if so then you will need to create a component based on the header render function and then import it and pass it like this

```
<FlatList ListHeaderComponent={HeaderComponent} />
```

if not then you can try to delete this line
`value={search}`

Comment: Yes i have this inside flatlist, can you please elaborate more, also i have edited the question for you.

Comment: You need to create a component ```HeaderComponent``` outside of the scope of the current component, then pass it to the flatlist as i mentioned above, you can also use this syntax if you wish to pass some props ```ListHeaderComponent={<HeaderComponent/>}```

Comment: you can refer to this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13365